# Can't get Slack "slash command" working with Azure Functions

Tags: azure, mime-types, content-type, slack, azure-functions

I'm trying to set up a simple Azure Function to integrate with a Slack 'slash' command. All seems to connect except Slack sends a content type of  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' which apparently Azure Functions don't know how to deal with.

I'd let it go as "un-doable" except Azure has a specific web hook setting for "Slack" which leads me to believe it should be able to work.

Any tips on how I can get this working?

Comment: Added the tag to make sure this is easily found. Hope the answer below helps.

Answer (score 1):

Slack WebHooks are indeed supported in Azure Functions. I'm not sure what error you ran into as it wasn't detailed, but here is a quick example of a slash command function that will echo the message back to the user:

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public static async Task<string> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    NameValueCollection data = await req.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();

    return data["text"];
}
```

function configuration (notice the WebHook type):

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "webHookType": "slack",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

**TIP:** One thing worth mentioning is that validation will be performed on the Slack request to ensure it did come from Slack. Since Slack doesn't let you bring the function secret as the token, you want to do the opposite (bring your Slack token to your function so that is used as the secret). In order to do that, grab your Slack token, open the "keys" panel for your function, delete your function level "default" key and recreate that (**name it "default"**) by pasting in the token you got from Slack.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Fabio's method but couldn't get it to work, as I wasn't sure if we are supposed to give slack a new url to send the post to (Tried variations of the url, but kept getting client error message).  I ended up just parsing the Form Data Manually. This seems to work pretty well each time.

```
string responseURL = "";
string command = "";
string content = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
string formdata = content.Split(';')[0];
string[] namevalues = formdata.Split('&');
NameValueCollection col = new NameValueCollection();

foreach (string value in namevalues)
{
    string[] nameValueItem = value.Split('=');
    col.Add(nameValueItem[0], nameValueItem[1]);
    log.Info(nameValueItem[0] + " - " + nameValueItem[1]);
    if(nameValueItem[0] == "response_url")
    {
        responseURL = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(nameValueItem[1]);
    }
    else if(nameValueItem[0] == "command")
    {
        command = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(nameValueItem[1]);

    }
}
```